# Set Gridview column width

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have two grids in my page of asp.net - vb.net with autogeneratecolumn set to true.
I bound both grids whose column are same but data are different.
Now I want to set width of columns in grid2 as in grid1.
Can any one help me for this.
I have tried to set in code behind as :

```
Private Sub grid2_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grid2.RowDataBound
    For i = 0 To grid1.Rows(0).Cells.Count - 1
        e.Row.Cells(i).Width = grid1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Width
    Next
End Sub
```

But `grid1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Width` gives me 0 as value.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your code on RowCreated event of Gridview like this:

```
Private Sub grid2_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grid2.RowCreated
For i = 0 To grid1.Rows(0).Cells.Count - 1
    e.Row.Cells(i).Width = grid1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Width
}
```

Comment: I have tried on RowCreated event of grid2 but even there grid1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Width gives 0 value.